# How do I get the equation number to be in the normal position

Tags: numbering

I want to write 4 equations in a single line  with one equation number.  I wrote

```
 \begin{equation}
     t=\gamma({t^'} +\frac{v}{c^2}{z^'})
     \text{,   }
    z=\gamma({z{^'} + v {t^'})
    \text{,   }
     x ={x^'}
    \text{,     }
    y ={y^'}
\end{equation}
```

and the equation number is right after the final equation rather than at the right margin as usual.

Comment: please provide an example that shows the problem. probably not related but `t^'`  wrong it should be `t'`

Comment: impossible to be sure with no example provided but I would guess the equation is too wide for the equation number to fit within the text width

Comment: get `! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.5      t=\gamma({t^'
` from this example

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
     t=\gamma({t^'} +\frac{v}{c^2}{z^'})
     \text{,   }
    z=\gamma({z{^'} + v {t^'})
    \text{,   }
     x ={x^'}
    \text{,     }
    y ={y^'}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.5      t=\gamma({t^'
                      } +\frac{v}{c^2}{z^'})
?
```

after any error, any pdf output is not intended to be usable, just a debuging aid.

Use `t'` never `t^'`

once that is fixed, the equation typesets as expected.

Note multiple spaces only make one space, I replaced by `\quad`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to see page size
\begin{equation}
     t=\gamma(t' +\frac{v}{c^2}z')
     \text{,}\quad
    z=\gamma(z' + v t')
    \text{,}\quad
     x =x'
    \text{,}\quad
    y =y'
\end{equation}
\hrule
\end{document}
```